# Upload document using angular 5 by calling a rest service

Tags: angular

I am trying to upload a document to our repository using Angular 5 and below is my Multipart/Form code and getting error which i pasted below. Angular 1.x code able to upload the document to our repository and i am doing very similar code other than one line set in the header which is (trasformrequest)

I tried sending the file as binary, bytes and very similar to Angular 1.x but i am getting the error. Here i have not set media type with application/octet-stream but still i am getting this error.

{"status":415,"code":"E_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE","message":"The specified media type application/octet-stream is not supported. Supported media types: [application/vnd.emc.documentum+json, application/vnd.emc.documentum+xml].","details":"Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported","id":"adcf72a5-f43e-4fa6-8cee-54db707122d2"}

// Angular 5 codeSetting the headers for the post

```
        let reqHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': undefined});
        reqHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/vnd.emc.documentum+json');
        //setting username 
        let username = "<username>";
        //setting password

        let password = "<password>";
        //creating converting to binary
        let authToken = btoa(username + ":" +password);
        //setting up the Authorization
        reqHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + authToken);

        //-Creating the format in the documentum way for the metadata.

        var docObj = this.buildPersistentObject(['r_object_type', 'dm_document', 'object_name', "test.pdf"])

        //enter code here`Forming Multipart/Form  -->

           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('data', new Blob([JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docObj))], {type: 'application/vnd.emc.documentum+json'}));
           fd.append('content', file);

        <!-- Sending the Post Request -->

        return this._http.post("http://localhost:8080/dctm-rest/repositories/demo/folders/0b01e24080008993/documents", fd, { headers: reqHeaders });

        <!-- Below is the error i am getting when i post the request. But i have not set application/octet-stream  sending only 

         {"status":415,"code":"E_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE","message":"The specified media type application/octet-stream is not supported. Supported media types: [application/vnd.emc.documentum+json, application/vnd.emc.documentum+xml].","details":"Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported","id":"adcf72a5-f43e-4fa6-8cee-54db707122d2"}
```

Working in Angular 1.x Code and only different i see is the headers['transformRequest'] = angular.identity which is not available in angular 5

```
       <!-- Creating Mulitpart Message -->
          var fd = new FormData()
        <!-- appending the metadata -->
        fd.append('metadata', new Blob([angular.toJson(data)], {type: dctmConstants.MIME.VND_DCTM_JSON}))
        <!-- appending the content -->
        fd.append('content', file)
        <!-- setting the content type to undefined -->
        headers[dctmConstants.HEADERS.CONTENT_TYPE] = undefined;

       // How this can be converted to angular 5

        headers['transformRequest'] = angular.identity;    
        data = fd

        <!-- Post Request call -->

        return this.http({method: 'POST',url: "http://localhost:8080/dctm-rest/repositories/demo/folders/0b01e24080008993/documents",headers: headers,data: data})
```

Please let me know your valuable suggestions. As i mentioned the in Angular 1.x i am able to upload the document to our repository but not with the Angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Try appending the file to the form data as TypeScript 'File' type.

Ex.

```
uploadDocument(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const baseUrl = 'http://someurl/documents';
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);

        return this.http.put(`${baseUrl}`, formData, {
            headers: this.headers
        });
}
```

Where file is the input of:

```
<input type="file" />
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I tried above code as well and it is not working as expected. Actually i am creating a PDF out of UI on the fly using jsPDF and i want to upload that.  Here i couldn't able to upload in Angular 5 whereas i am able to do in angular 1.x. The difference i am seeing is setting transformrequest = angular.identity which i couldn't able to set.

Answer (score 0):

```
In Angular Js 6, i am able to create a multipart/form using the below format.

const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
             'Accept': 'application/vnd.emc.documentum+json',
              'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authToken,

            })
          };

var fd = new FormData();`enter code here`
 fd.append('data', JSON.stringify(docObj));
        fd.append('content', body) 

return this.http.post(URL, fd, httpOptions);
```